# Which hook is suitable for ignoring some (.exe , .xml) file?

Tags: hook, gitlab

Which hook is suitable for ignoring the **.exe, .dll, .pdf, binary file** from committing in GitLab. I don`t know which one should be used. (pre-commit, post-commit, .... and so on). But my final moto is that user should not commit the Binary file(.exe, .dll, .pdf) in git branches.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `.gitignore`  file

Comment: @Fairy You are correct but I have nearly 400 repositories. I search the way to add the `.gitignore` file in every project. But I did not get the way for it. So only I go for hook concept. Do you have any idea to add the `.gitignore` file in each and every project without manually?

Comment: You could use the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html) to create the files in your projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pre-receive` or `pre-commit` hook is suitable for this kind of operation